# can A call approve B to spend token though A have no tokens in his account?

Tags: erc-20

can A call approve B to spend token though A have no tokens in his account?
does function approve require to check balance of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can A call approve B to spend token though A have no tokens

Yes. `approve()` sets a spending limit but it is not necessarily funded.

> does function approve require to check balance of A?

No. It merely sets the allowance.

In case this is counter-intuitive, it is because the balance check happens when the "spender" tries to exercise the privilege granted by `approve`.

This is acceptable.

1. Alice has no money.
2. Alice approves Bob to spend 100 tokens.
3. Alice receives 100 tokens.
4. Bob spends 100 tokens from Alice's account.

If Bob tries to spend more money than Alice has, then the `transfer` will fail.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You probably meant "tokens" instead of "wei".

Comment: Good catch. Fixed it.